# How to ask if selected row in JTable is visible?

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jtable

I have this function

```
private static void autoScrollToRow(JTable table) {
      JViewport viewport = (JViewport) table.getParent();
        Rectangle cellRectangle = table.getCellRect(table.getSelectedRow(), 0, true);
        Rectangle visibleRectangle = viewport.getVisibleRect();
        table.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(cellRectangle.x, cellRectangle.y, (int) visibleRectangle.getWidth(), (int) visibleRectangle.getHeight()));
}
```

and this function scrolls in that way that currently selected row is first in tableView. How to edit this function so it only do scrolling if selected row is out of sight?
(Something like `if(table.sellectedRowVisibleOnScreen(true))`)

Comment: AFAIK, that is the way the scrollRectToVisible(...) method works. If the selected row is above the top of the viewport the viewport will be scrolled so the row is at the top. If the selected row is below the viewport the viewport will be scrolled so the row is at the bottom. Post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem. That is create a JFrame with a JTable that has data with the row numbers in a column. Then add a JTextField. The ActionListener of the text field should attempt to scroll to the entered row number. We should be able to copy/paste/compile and test the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to edit this function so it only do scrolling if selected row is out of sight?

You don't do anything special.

This is the default behavior of the `scrollToRect(...)` method (as I explained in my comment).

All you need in your method is:

```
Rectangle cellRectangle = table.getCellRect(table.getSelectedRow(), 0, true);
table.scrollRectToVisible(cellRectangle);
```

1. If the selected row is above the top of the viewport, the viewport will be scrolled so the row is at the top.
2. If the selected row is below the viewport the viewport, will be scrolled so the row is at the bottom.
3. If the selected row is already visible in the viewport, no scrolling is done.

Answer (score 1):

You already have two Rectangles in your method that you can test.

```
private static void autoScrollToRow(JTable table) {
    JViewport viewport = (JViewport) table.getParent();
    Rectangle cellRectangle = table.getCellRect(table.getSelectedRow(), 0, true);
    Rectangle visibleRectangle = viewport.getVisibleRect();
    
    if (!visibleRectangle.contains(cellRectangle)) {
        int width = (int) visibleRectangle.getWidth();
        int height = (int) visibleRectangle.getHeight();
        table.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(
                cellRectangle.x, cellRectangle.y, width, height));
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually works only in one direction, it scrolls down but it does not return it up anymore.

Comment: @Raskoljnikovic: Since I don't have code I can run and test, I can't determine why the code doesn't work.  I suggest printing out the rectangle values.